# Different Combinations of Checkboxes producing different results using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

What I would like to do is give a fairly basic recommendation to the user, in this example i have 5 options and 3 answers. The answers would be assigned to specific combinations of the the checkbox values.

For example checking 'A' alone may produce result 1, while if both 'A' and 'B' are checked then the answer is result 2. D,E,A may give result 3 while B,E,A give result 2. Hopefully you get the point.

```
 <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="A" />Choice A<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="B" />Choice B<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="C" />Choice C<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="D" />Choice D<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="E" />Choice E<br />   
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="answer">
</form>
```

and the jquery would be something along these lines

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).val(["A","B","C"]).is(':checked'))
        $('.result1').show(value);
    else
        $('.result1').hide(value);

    if ($(this).val(["A","D","E"]).is(':checked'))
        $('.result2').show(value);
    else
        $('.result2').hide(value);
```

Does this make sense? I'd appreciate any help. I've added my issue to jsfiddle if anyone wants to get a better look at my issue

http://jsfiddle.net/gdjones83/tJY69/32/

Answer (score 0):

You need two helper functions:

This little extension to jQuery will let you know all `val()` results of a set of elements, getting them as an array:

```
$.fn.multipleVals = function() {
    var result = new Array();
    $(this).each(function() {
        result.push($(this).val());
    })
    return result;
}
```

And this one, will help you to know if two arrays contains the same elements (it's not the same to if they are equal or not. To be equal both needs to have the same elements with the same keys in the same order. We're not checking that):

```
function arraysSameElements(array1, array2) {
    if(array1.length == array2.length) {
        for(var i in array1)
            if($.inArray(array1[i], array2) == -1)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Having this, now you can do something like this:

```
if (arraysSameElements($("form input:checkbox:checked").multipleVals(), ["A","B","C"]))
    $('.result1').show(value);
else
    $('.result1').hide(value);
```

In `$("form input:checkbox:checked")` you get all the checked checkboxes (:P) into `form`. Then, with `multipleVals` you put all the `.val()` results into an array, and compare them with a formed array having the answers you need to show one result or another.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand your approach here so I will give it a go as soon as I get some free time and hopefully fix this problem.

Comment: Great :-) Hope it helps. Bye!